# An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue on windows 7

Tags: ruby, xamarin, rubygems, xamarin.android

I am getting the following error while trying to install 
**gem install -v '1.8.3'**
sys conf: windows 7 64 bit 8 gb Ram

> gem install json -v '1.8.3' Temporarily enhancing PATH to include
>   DevKit... Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   ERROR:  Error installing json:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ex t/generator
> ```
>
> C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160512-48840-1qfw8j8.rb
>   extconf.rb creating Makefile
>
> current directory:
>   C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/ge nerator
>   make "DESTDIR=" clean
>
> current directory:
>   C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/ge nerator
>   make "DESTDIR=" generating generator-i386-mingw32.def compiling
>   generator.c In file included from
>   c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h:33:0,
>                    from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
>                    from generator.c:1: c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:109:14: error: size of array
>   'ruby_chec k_sizeof_voidp' is negative In file included from
>   c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h:33:0,
>                    from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
>                    from generator.c:1: c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function
>   'rb_obj_wb_unprotect':
>   c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1234:9: warning: cast to
>   pointer from i nteger of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
>   c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1235:6: warning: cast to
>   pointer from i nteger of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
>   c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1238:2: warning: cast to
>   pointer from i nteger of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
>   c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function
>   'rb_obj_written': c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1253:9:
>   warning: cast to pointer from i nteger of different size
>   [-Wint-to-pointer-cast] c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h: In
>   function 'rb_num2char_inline':
>   c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1324:35: warning: cast to
>   pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
>   c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1324:35: warning: cast to
>   pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
>   c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1324:35: warning: cast to
>   pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
>   c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1325:9: warning: cast to
>   pointer from i nteger of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
>   c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1325:9: warning: cast to
>   pointer from i nteger of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
>   c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1325:9: warning: cast to
>   pointer from i nteger of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
>   c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_class_of':
>   c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1642:12: warning: cast to
>   pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
>   c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_type':
>   c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1659:12: warning: cast to
>   pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast] In file
>   included from generator.c:1:0: ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h: In function
>   'fbuffer_append_str': ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:127:25: warning: cast to
>   pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
>   ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:127:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of
>   different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast] ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:127:25:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
>   [-Wint-to-pointer-cast] generator.c: In function
>   'convert_UTF8_to_JSON_ASCII': generator.c:129:35: warning: cast to
>   pointer from integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c:129:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
>   size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:129:35: warning: cast to
>   pointer from integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c:130:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
>   size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:130:38: warning: cast to
>   pointer from integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c:130:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
>   size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c: In function
>   'convert_UTF8_to_JSON': generator.c:227:23: warning: cast to pointer
>   from integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c:227:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
>   size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:227:23: warning: cast to
>   pointer from integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c:228:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
>   size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:228:25: warning: cast to
>   pointer from integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c:228:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
>   size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c: In function
>   'cState_configure': generator.c:553:15: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:553:15:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:553:15: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:554:34:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:554:34: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:554:34:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:561:15: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:561:15:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:561:15: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:562:33:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:562:33: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:562:33:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:569:15: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:569:15:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:569:15: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:570:40:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:570:40: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:570:40:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:577:15: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:577:15:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:577:15: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:578:36:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:578:36: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:578:36:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:585:15: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:585:15:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:585:15: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:586:37:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:586:37: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:586:37:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c: In function 'set_state_ivars':
>   generator.c:634:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
>   size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:634:21: warning: cast to
>   pointer from integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c:634:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
>   size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:636:24: warning: cast to
>   pointer from integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c:636:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
>   size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:636:24: warning: cast to
>   pointer from integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c: In function 'generate_json_object': generator.c:721:20:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:721:20: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:721:20:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c: In function 'generate_json_array':
>   generator.c:767:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
>   size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:767:20: warning: cast to
>   pointer from integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c:767:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
>   size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c: In function
>   'isArrayOrObject': generator.c:924:23: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:924:23:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:924:23: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:925:15:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:925:15: warning: cast to pointer from
>   integer of different size [-Wi nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:925:15:
>   warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
>   nt-to-pointer-cast] generator.c: In function 'cState_indent_set':
>   generator.c:1049:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of
>   different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:1049:11: warning:
>   cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
>   int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:1049:11: warning: cast to pointer
>   from integer of different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c:1058:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of
>   different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:1058:32: warning:
>   cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
>   int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:1058:32: warning: cast to pointer
>   from integer of different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:
>   In function 'cState_space_set': generator.c:1087:11: warning: cast to
>   pointer from integer of different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c:1087:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of
>   different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:1087:11: warning:
>   cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
>   int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:1096:31: warning: cast to pointer
>   from integer of different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c:1096:31: warning: cast to pointer from integer of
>   different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:1096:31: warning:
>   cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
>   int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c: In function
>   'cState_space_before_set': generator.c:1123:11: warning: cast to
>   pointer from integer of different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c:1123:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of
>   different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:1123:11: warning:
>   cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
>   int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:1132:38: warning: cast to pointer
>   from integer of different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c:1132:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of
>   different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:1132:38: warning:
>   cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
>   int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c: In function 'cState_object_nl_set':
>   generator.c:1161:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of
>   different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:1161:11: warning:
>   cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
>   int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:1161:11: warning: cast to pointer
>   from integer of different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c:1169:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of
>   different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:1169:35: warning:
>   cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
>   int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:1169:35: warning: cast to pointer
>   from integer of different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:
>   In function 'cState_array_nl_set': generator.c:1196:11: warning: cast
>   to pointer from integer of different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c:1196:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of
>   different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:1196:11: warning:
>   cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
>   int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:1204:34: warning: cast to pointer
>   from integer of different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast]
>   generator.c:1204:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of
>   different size [-W int-to-pointer-cast] generator.c:1204:34: warning:
>   cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
>   int-to-pointer-cast] make: *** [generator.o] Error 1
>
> make failed, exit code 2
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3  for inspection. Results
>   logged to
>   C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/jso
>   n-1.8.3/gem_make.out

Answer (score 0):

You should use right ruby and devkit.

[rubyinstaller.org](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)

You can try to uninstall your ruby and devkit,and reintall right ruby and devkit.